# ruby on rails - Two digit precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails

iam working on RoR code, i want to know how to find two digit precision for the numbers

a = 0.7

b = 5

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Always your standard

```
a = "%.2f" % 0.2
b = "%.2f" % 5
```

#### 0.20

#### 5.00

Outputs strings though, so you may need `("%.2f" % 0.2).to_i` or cast later (`a.to_i`).

Answer (score 3):

[`number_with_precision`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001687). If you're looking to express them as currency, use [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001684).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to store those numbers and their precision in the database you should set up decimal fields.

```
 add_column :table_name, :column_name, :decimal,  :precision => 5, :scale => 2
```

Options for a decimal field:

- :precision : maximum number of digits in a value
- :scale : number of digits after the decimal place

With a decimal field you will never need the helper methods to limit the precision after the decimal place.